# How do you make this style without table?

Tags: css

layout would look like this:

```
abc     1 2 
bcd     1 2 3 4
eaasd   5 6
```

I heard that it's not good to make layout with table, so what would you do in this case?

Comment: Use div or nbsp; with <br>

Comment: Two column three rows?

Comment: I rolled back your new edit. You can't change the question to another question, it is already answered.  Please ask your new question as an independent one.

Comment: And please mark one of existing answers as accepted if they did answer your first question

Comment: I forgot to mention I was using li. That was why I said I didn't want a table and updated the question. There was only one question. ketan's answer is close.

Comment: @Gaga Ask it as new question, answers here are based on that no bullet list.

Comment: Fine, but I did incline an answer without a table. ketan's answer inspired me. Marked.

Comment: @bigOTHER It was my mistake that I didn't mention I was using li. I edited the answer to complement the original question not to chanting it to another question. That's why it has the edit feature even the question is answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make div based layout like following way. And use `display:inline-block`.

```css
.main > div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div>abc</div><div>1 2</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
<div>bcd</div><div>1 2 3 4</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
<div>eaasd</div><div>5 6</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to display tabular data, just use a table.

If you want to display exactly like in the example you could use `<pre>` but this may be very different from what you expect.

Comment: In this case you can create an unordered list with `<ul>` and `<li>`, please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Lists

Comment: I meant how do you make that layout in this case?

Comment: Please read the link provided, we are here to help you with questions not to do your job.

Answer (score 3):

It's not good to use tables for general layout but not tabular data. So for your case, using table is the best idea.

Comment: In this case you can use the `<ul>` ro list your lines and another inline list to list elements per line. by using the `<ul>` it will be lay-outed

Answer (score 1):

Try using CSS like `inline-block` or `flexbox`.  Here's an example with `inline-block`:

```
<div class="column">
  <p>
  abc
  </p>
  <p>
  bcd
  </p>
  <p>
  eaasd
  </p>
</div>
```

...

With CSS:

```
.column {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

See the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azc669dq/).

Also check out the grid system of Bootstrap for an alternative (if your content is less than 13 columns wide): http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid